# Using a logical operator within .includes()--getting an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, operators

I have some code that appends a file extension icon next to a specific document---i.e. all of the .pdf files have a PDF icon right next to it.

Some documents end in `doc` and `DOCX`, and so I tried to implement `.includes('doc' || 'DOCX')`, but I'm receiving an error and `DOCX` ends up not loading. As such I've just done `.includes('ext name')) { return`...etc for every variation, but it's cumbersome and I want to see if they can be shortened.

I tried to research if logical operators were allowed with `.includes()`, but nothing came up. Is this why I'm getting an error, or is there another reason?

**Here's my JS:**

```
function docType(fileName) {
    let docImg = "<img src='https://url/Current.ashx/docx.gif'  />"
    let msgImg = "<img src='https://url/Current.ashx/msg.gif'   />"

    let docStr = fileName.split(".");
      for (var i = 0; i < docStr.length; i++) {
       if (docStr[i].includes('doc' || 'DOCX')) { return docStr[i] = docImg;  } 
  else if (docStr[i].includes('msg')) { return docStr[i] = msgImg;  } 

      }
  } // docType
```

Comment: Won't work. Need to check individually with `includes` or do a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than multiple includes or a regex you can also use `Array#some()`

Try

```
if(['doc','DOCX'].some(s = > docStr[i].includes(s)))
```

Comment: That did it the trick and was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Probably no real reason to check the parts before the last `.` either if wanting to cjheck file extensions only

Answer (score 1):

`includes` checks against the value that is passed as an argument. It does not evaluate any user code during the check. You will need to use

```
if (docStr[i].includes('doc') || docStr[i].includes('doc'))
```

Comment: `docStr[i]` would be a string from `split()`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, I'm tired :-/